# handling dataset if some columns have sparse data

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

1)if in a dataset 8 columns and of them 3 columns have sparse data[lots of missing values].can anyone tell me what are the general practices followed to transform this data before modelling.
I know we can do imputation to fill missing values or just remove sparse columns,
2)how to decide whether to impute values in sparse column or delete them? and 
3)if i choose to impute in which cases do i have to do central imputation and knn imputation?

4) Finally, how does these above scenarios change when my dataset has large number of column/features?

Sorry for asking many questions,i think all these questions are related so i put them in single question.

Comment: What do you mean by sparse data?  Do you mean you have a lot of missing values?

Comment: yes i meant lot of missing values in 3 columns of my data set

Comment: what proportion is missing?  What drives the missingness?

Comment: 70% of data is missing, missing because values are not recorded (don't know the reason for not recording them)